# Mock classes and interfaces, fully or partially in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocking

What is the best way to mock classes and interfaces, fully or partially in TypeScript?

Jest is a popular test stack with mocking support, however according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091438/jest-how-to-mock-one-specific-method-of-a-class) mocking single methods, classes and interfaces isn't supported in a fluent manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous mocking libraries specifically for TypeScript. [Substitute.js](https://github.com/ffMathy/FluffySpoon.JavaScript.Testing.Faking) is an excellent one. At the time of writing it addresses shortcomings in others, including:

- Fluent API. ts-mockito has a fluent API, however it is unable to mock interfaces. This is a show-stopper.
- Ability to create partial mocks.

It can also be fairly simply achieved with jest, as follows:

```
ClientDefaultImpl.prototype.authorize = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(
            () => Promise.resolve('xxx'));
```

**Edit:**

[ts-mockito](https://github.com/NagRock/ts-mockito) supports mocking of classes (and interfaces?) now.

Comment: Answering my own question that arose yesterday and sharing a few hours of research.