# jest.mockImplementation() fails to stub method's return value inside constructor()

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am attempting to stub an instance method by following the top rated response in this topic: [Jest: How to mock one specific method of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091438/jest-how-to-mock-one-specific-method-of-a-class)

The method `.getFileName()` should normally take the 3rd argument and return the file name, in this case `file.js`. I thought I stubbed it to override and return `scriptTag.js`.

It still returns `file.js` meaning `.mockImplementation()` is not running during `constructor()`.

Is there any way to override values assigned in the constructor with a spy or stubbing function? This would be helpful when instantiating inside a beforeEach, when I want to override the default constructor values.

**`ScriptTag.ts`**

```
  public localFileName: string;

  constructor(storeDomain: string, generalToken: string, filePath: string) {
    super(storeDomain, generalToken);
    this.localFileName = this.getFileName(this.filePath);
  }

  public getFileName(filePathOrUrl: string): string {
    const fileNameMatch: string[]|null = filePathOrUrl.match(/\/{1}(\w+.js)$/);
    if (Boolean(fileNameMatch)) { return fileNameMatch![1]; }
    else { throw Error("Filename not found"); }
  }
```

**`ScriptTag.test.ts`**

```
test("constructor()", () => {
  const scriptTag: ScriptTag = new ScriptTag("subdomain.shopify.com", 'generalTokenValue', "../path/to/file.js");
  const spy = jest
    .spyOn(scriptTag, "getFileName")
    .mockImplementation(() => "scriptTag.js");

  // expect(scriptTag.getFileName('x')).toEqual('scriptTag.js');
  expect(scriptTag.localFileName).toEqual('scriptTag.js');

});
```

`terminal`

```
  ✕ constructor() (10ms)

  ● constructor()

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "scriptTag.js"
    Received: "file.js"

      17 |   
      18 |   // expect(scriptTag.getFileName('x')).toEqual('scriptTag.js');
    > 19 |   expect(scriptTag.localFileName).toEqual('scriptTag.js');
         |                                   ^
      20 |   
      21 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (functions/src/classes/__tests__/ScriptTag.test.ts:19:35)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate the `ScriptTag` class, then the value of `localFileName` property is already assigned to `file.js`.

After instantiation, you use `jest.spyOn` to spy on the `getFileName` method. It's late.

You need spy on and make a stub for `getFileName` method before instantiating the `ScriptTag` class.

E.g.

`ScriptTag.ts`:

```js
export class ScriptTag {
  localFileName = '';
  filePath = 'file.js';
  constructor(storeDomain: string, generalToken: string, filePath: string) {
    this.localFileName = this.getFileName(this.filePath);
  }

  public getFileName(filePathOrUrl: string): string {
    const fileNameMatch: string[] | null = filePathOrUrl.match(/\/{1}(\w+.js)$/);
    if (Boolean(fileNameMatch)) {
      return fileNameMatch![1];
    } else {
      throw Error('Filename not found');
    }
  }
}
```

`ScriptTag.test.ts`:

```js
import { ScriptTag } from './ScriptTag';

describe('ScriptTag', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    jest.spyOn(ScriptTag.prototype, 'getFileName').mockImplementation(() => 'scriptTag.js');
    const scriptTag: ScriptTag = new ScriptTag('subdomain.shopify.com', 'generalTokenValue', '../path/to/file.js');
    expect(scriptTag.localFileName).toEqual('scriptTag.js');
    expect(scriptTag.getFileName).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Unit test result

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59266532/ScriptTag.test.ts (10.73s)
  ScriptTag
    ✓ should pass (7ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.787s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59266532