# Testing TypeScript with Jest: "no overload matches this call"

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, apollo, apollo-server

I'm working on testing an Apollo Server `RESTDataSource` using Jest.  My app is written in TypeScript.  My class, `CDCDataSource` extends the abstract class [RESTDataSource](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/master/packages/apollo-datasource-rest/src/RESTDataSource.ts) which itself extends the abstract class `DataSource`.  `RESTDataSource` has the method `get` which allows you to pull data from an external REST data source.  It is this method I wish to mock, since I wish to mock the external data source.

```
  protected async get<TResult = any>(
    path: string,
    params?: URLSearchParamsInit,
    init?: RequestInit,
  ): Promise<TResult> {
    return this.fetch<TResult>(
      Object.assign({ method: 'GET', path, params }, init),
    );
  }
```

However, when I try to mock this method using Jest's `spyOn` -- following the second answer here: [Jest: How to mock one specific method of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091438/jest-how-to-mock-one-specific-method-of-a-class) --

```
import CDCDataSource from '../CDCDataSource';

test('Test', () => {
    let dataSource = new CDCDataSource();
    let spy = jest.spyOn(dataSource, 'get').mockImplementation(() => 'Hello');
    expect(dataSource.get()).toBe('Hello');
```

However, I get the TypeScript error

> TS2768: No overload matches this call

over the `get` in `jest.spyOn(dataSource,'get')`

and I get

[image]

over the `get` in

`expect(dataSource.get()).toBe('Hello');`

So it would seem that part of the issue is that this is a protect method --  I'm unclear how to test this method so as to be able to mock the API.

My `tsconfig.json` is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

This is a Node Apollo Server project (using Node 12.14.0 and TypeScript 3.8.3)

Thanks for any clues!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to access a `protected` method.

If you don't want to or can't rearchitect your class, you can use `ts-ignore` to suppress the error.

```
    // @ts-ignore`
    let spy = jest.spyOn(dataSource, 'get').mockImplementation(() => 'Hello');
```

Or you can extend the original class, with a class made only for testing, that will have a public method that will just proxy to the protected method.

```
test('Protected method',()=>{

  class Test extends OriginalClass {
    testProtected(){
      super.protectedMethod()
    }
  }
  let dataSource = new Test();
  let spy = jest.spyOn(dataSource, 'testProtected').mockImplementation(() => 'Hello');
})
```

Comment: When you are writing tests it is better to use `@ts-expect-error`

Comment: I can't re-architect the class as it's not mine -- it comes from Apollo.  I'll follow the proxy method...