# Jest Mock Variables Declared Inside a Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

**Problem**

I'm trying to test a function I created, but I need to mock two consts declared inside the function.

I've found posts on how to mock a function called in another function, but I would like to avoid having to declare both consts inside of a separate function and calling the separate function inside my function.

***Does anyone have any advice on how I can mock the consts windowWidth and WindowHeight inside windowDimensions below?***

**Code**

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

interface WindowDimensions {
    minWindowDimension: number;
    maxWindowDimension: number;
}

export function windowDimensions(): WindowDimensions {
         const windowWidth = Math.round(Dimensions.get("window").width);
         const windowHeight = Math.round(
           Dimensions.get("window").height
         );
         const minWindowDimension = Math.min(windowWidth, windowHeight);
         const maxWindowDimension = Math.max(windowWidth, windowHeight);
         return { minWindowDimension, maxWindowDimension };
       }
```

Comment: No, you cannot mock a local variable (and you're not supposed to: the local workings of the function is what you are trying to test!). You should mock `Dimensions` or `Dimensions.get`.

Comment: I had a feeling mocking Dimensions would be the way to go!  How would I go about mocking Dimensions.get ?

Comment: You said "*I've found posts on how to mock a function called in another function*"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091438/jest-how-to-mock-one-specific-method-of-a-class

Comment: It's a bit different approach, but you could take the windowWidth and windowHeight as arguments of the function so that you could test the function by mocking those arguments.