# Jest: How to mock one specific method of an already-mocked class

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have some classes that have been mocked out according to the Jest docs [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock).

I need to be able to update the methods to these classes post- `mockImplementation()`. The Jest docs specify how to do this [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-or-mockimplementationonce).

The problem is when I replace my mocks this way, I'm essentially resetting my class mock and all the methods are now reset and return undefined.

What I'm looking to do is modify one method on my mocked class without using `mockImplementation()`; I don't want to re-mock the whole class again, if that makes sense.

I have come up with a solution, but I don't like it and feel there is something better out there. My solution is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68969741/10044909) but I'll also provide it below.

My solution:

```js
const instanceOfPreviouslyMockedClass = new PreviouslyMockedClass();

PreviouslyMockedClass.mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
        // "Import" the previous class methods at the top
        ...instanceOfPreviouslyMockedClass,

        // Then overwrite the ones you wanna update
        myUpdatedMethod: jest.fn(() => {
            console.log(
                "This method is updated, the others are present and unaltered"
            );
        }),
    };
});
```

So far this solution does the trick. But it just seems so hacky and I wanted to see if anyone had a better solution. Thanks for any solutions or extra insight!

Comment: What is your mock scope?

Comment: The class mocks are being implemented in a __mocks__ directory. I want to modify them within a describe block, test block, or beforeAll/beforeEach, essentially anywhere after the original implementation. If this isn’t what you are referring to, could you please elaborate on what you mean by the mocks scope?